# Ionic NavController.pop() refesh destination page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, controller, navigation, ionic-storage

I have an `ionic` application and I use `ionic` storage. I have two pages, `page1` and `page2`. In `page2.ts` I add some information to the storage and then I call `NavController.pop()` to return to `page1`. In `page1` I want to show this new information that was added to the storage.

The code is like this:
PAGE2.TS

```
onSubmit() {
        let _actividad = new Actividad(this.event.nameActividad, this.event.timeStartsIntensidad, this.event.timeStartsDescanso, this.event.timeStartsCalentamiento, this.event.timeStartsRelajacion, this.event.numberIntervalos);
        this.strgCtrl.set(this.event.nameActividad, _actividad);
        console.log(_actividad.getNameActividad());
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
```

Heare, I creat an object and I store it and the call to page1.

PAGE1.HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let x of actividades"> 
            <button ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail item-start>
                <img src="assets/imgs/abdominales.jpg">
            </ion-thumbnail>
            <h2>{{x.nameActividad_act}}</h2>
            <p>Intervalos: 10</p>
            <p>Intensidad: 10</p>
            </button>
            <button  ion-button class="disable-hover button button-md button-default button-default-md button-md-primary" item-end>Empezar</button>
        </ion-item>
```

PAGE1.TS

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.strgCtrl.forEach( (value, key, index) => {
            this.actividades.push(value);
        })
    }
```

Well, this code do what I want, if I storage a new activity and refresh Page1 I can show it. But, how can I do this without refreshing page1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In page1 .ts file:

```
goToPage2() {
var _that = this;
//callback
var callbackFunction = function (params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _that.strgCtrl.forEach( (value, key, index) => {
      _that.actividades.push(value);
    });
    resolve();
  });
}
// push page...
this.navController.push(page2, {
  callback: callbackFunction
});
}
```

In page2 .ts file:

```
callback;
ionViewWillEnter() {
   this.callback = this.navParams.get("callback");
}
ionViewWillLeave() {
   this.callback();
}
```

or:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.callback();
    this.navCtrl.pop();
}
```

you can also pass some parameters.

Comment: Hi Amin,
firstly thank you so mucho for your answer. I0'm trying to implement it but I get this error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" in the page1.ts in line this.actividades.push(value);
Can you help me with that? I'm new using ionic so I still not understand tipical errors